# How to evaluate an expression with variables in R?

Tags: r, variables, expression, eval

I expect this code to set `plt` equal to 10:

```
> var = "plt"
> eval(paste0(var, "<-", 10))
[1] "plt<-10"
```

But instead, it returns a string.

I tried `eval(as.expression(paste0(var, "<-", 10)))` and other options, but it still doesn't give the expected result.

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question.
   -- Thomas Lumley
      R-help (February 2005)

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @Thomas To execute a function whose name is passed to another function as an argument. Like `function(type, ...) eval(parse(text=paste0("plt <- ", type, "(...)"`.

Comment: @Anton In that case, please see Roland's answer.

Comment: Usually passing the name of a function around is a very very bad thing to do. Pass the **actual** function around instead. `foo("sqrt")` is bad, since you have to jump through various hoops to get the function back. `foo(sqrt)` is better: `foo=function(f){f(2)}` neatly applies the function passed in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand your comment correctly there is no reason to dive into the shark-infested waters of `eval(parse())`. Try something like this instead:

```
myfun <- function(x, fun) {
  if (is.character(fun)) fun <- match.fun(fun)
  fun(x)
}

myfun(1:5, mean)
#[1] 3
myfun(1:5, "mean")
#[1] 3
```

Answer (score 3):

See: `?parse`. Your demo code:

```
> var = "plt"
> eval(parse(text = paste0(var, "<-", 10)))
> plt
[1] 10
```

---

**Update:** based on @Anton's comment about the original goal - what about:

```
> f <- function(type, ...) {
+     assign('plt', do.call(deparse(substitute(type)), list(...)), envir = .GlobalEnv)
+ }
> f(mean, x = 1:20)
> plt
[1] 10.5
```

PS: I still trying to implement what the OP is after, not what he might or should be after -- that's why I used above `assign` and `.GlobalEnv`, although it's not a great idea BTW.

Comment: @Anton Seriously, don't use this. It will result in code of very poor quality (hard to understand and maintain). There are always better alternatives to `eval(parse())`.